# Proper self.view.frame in viewWillAppear while showing navigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm showing `navigationBar` in parent view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Then, in next view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    /* ... */
    NSLog(@"%i, %g", self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden,
            self.view.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    /* ... */
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%i, %g", self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden, 
            self.view.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    NSLog(@"%i, %g", self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden, 
            self.view.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%i, %g", self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden, 
            self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

outputs:

```
-[viewDidLoad]: 1, 416
-[viewWillAppear:]: 0, 460
-[viewWillLayoutSubviews]: 0, 416
-[viewDidAppear:]: 0, 416
```

As you see `viewWillAppear` gets wrong `self.view.frame.size.height`. It would be OK to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, but it was introduced in iOS5. Is it possible to get proper frame height in viewWillAppear?

Comment: why is 460 wrong?  480-20 (status bar height) = 460

Comment: sorry, I'm *showing* navigation bar ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best solution I've got so far:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    /* recalculate frame size */
    CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(application.statusBarOrientation))
        size = CGSizeMake(size.height, size.width);
    if (!application.statusBarHidden)
        size.height -= MIN(application.statusBarFrame.size.width,
                           application.statusBarFrame.size.height);

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.height = size.height -
                        self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    self.view.frame = frame;

    /* ... */
}
```